# Right join with group by clause in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Please share me your input on below

I have two dataset in oracle 11g

set 1:

```
empid-Qtr-salary
1-Q3FY16-2000
1-Q2FY16-1000
2-Q3FY16-2000
2-Q2FY16-3000
2-Q1FY16-4000
2-Q4FY15-5000
3-Q2FY16-7000
3-Q1FY16-8000
enter code here
```

set 2

```
id-qtr
1-Q3FY16
2-Q2FY16
3-Q1FY16
4-Q4FY15
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT IS

```
enter code here
1-Q3FY16-2000
1-Q2FY16-1000
1-Q1FY16-NULL
1-Q4FY15-NULL
2-Q3FY16-2000
2-Q2FY16-3000
2-Q1FY16-4000
2-Q4FY15-5000
3-Q3FY16-NULL
3-Q2FY16-3000
3-Q1FY16-7000
3-Q4FY15-NULL
```

tried with right out join . No luck.

```
select s1.empid,s2.qtr,s1.salary from set1 s1
```

right join set2 s2 on s2.qtr=s1.qtr
group by s1.empid,s2.qtr,s1.salary

Comment: What's that about "Group by clause" in your title? What's that got to do with anything?

Comment: Also, what do you know about the most elementary SQL select statement? WHAT ARE YOU SELECTING in your attempt?

Comment: select s1.empid,s2.qtr,s1.salary from set1 s1 
right join set2 s2 on s2.qtr=s1.qtr
group by s1.empid,s2.qtr,s1.salary

Comment: is it possible to perform right join with in empid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right outer join you want is with the CROSS JOIN of the list of empid's (which should be in a table of its own) and the list of quarters. Something like this:

```
select s1.empid, s1.qtr, s1.salary
from s1 right other join
((select distinct empid from s1) s3 cross join s2) t
on s1.empid = t.empid and s1.qtr = t.qtr
```

For every PAIR (empid, qtr) you want to pick up the salary, and if there is no salary, you want NULL instead - that's what the right outer join does. The cross join creates the set of ALL possible combinations of empid and qtr.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy .thanks a lot. finally i made it based on your suggested query

Comment: Then please mark the question as Answered so it does not show up on the unanswered questions list.   Cheers,  mathguy